# Neo Sans Pro websafe alternative

Tags: web-safe-fonts

In our current project we were given a sets of web designs, but those included Neo Sans Pro font, however, we can not use that one - is there a websafe alternative for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I was looking for some alternatives - here's what I found on google fonts,

however **be careful if you neeed diacritics** – especially Caron and Ring ...see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(diacritic)):

for more info.

**FONTS:**
Armata - http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Armata

Titillium Web - http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Titillium+Web

(no carons, no rings) Ropa Sans - http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Ropa+Sans

Exo - http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Exo

Answer (score 1):

Open Sans would be your best option